# SQL query for matching Object Variables to Rows in a table

Tags: sql, match

I have a table with 13 columns. Each row in my table represents a business rule which is nothing but combination of Column values. So take for example

- Rule 1 : Column 1 == A and Column 3 == B and Column 8 == C
- Rule 2 : Column 6 == P and Column 7 == Q and Column 9 == R
- Rule 3 : Column 2 == Y
- Rule 4 : Column 5 == H and Column 1 == K

I am receiving an Object which has all the 13 fields. I want to write a method where if the values of the fields matches any of the rows, I return

- All the columns matched
- RuleID (a separate column in table corresponding to each row. like a `publicID`)

I am struggling to write the query for the same. Can I write one query to that will effectively check if the value of Object variables matches any row in the table? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the table structure and some idea of what that mysterious Object is.

Comment: The table is just a normal database table with 13 columns. Each Column corresponds to the Object Variable. The table has 13 rows providing values to some of the columns. So Rule 1 only has values for Column 1, 2 and 3 and the rest are null. Rule 2 has values for COlumn 4 and 5 and the rest are null. My object has fields returned from an Integration service. I want to check if my object variable values correspond to any of the row in the database

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add the table definition (as `create table` statements) some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)